# Synonymising tags slavic and slavic-languages

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

As of today, there are two independent tag [slavic](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slavic) and [slavic-languages](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slavic-languages). From their description it is clear that the two should be synonyms; but alas, I have not enough tag score to do it on my own.

Comment: Do we have a similar situation for other language families?

Comment: Dunno, I stumbled over this one accidentally.

Comment: Emptied the tag slavic in favour of slavic-languages which was more populated.